# How to count after matching across tables without creating new table

Tags: sql

I have two tables: one (customer_table) with customer IDs (customer_id) and customer states (customer_state), another (purchase_table) with customer IDs (customer_id) and purchases in dollars (customer_purchase). How do I get the sum of purchases by state?

Here is some example data:

customer_table

customer_id: 1101,1102,1103,1104
customer_state: 'DE','NJ','DE','PA'

purchase_table

customer_id: 1101, 1102, 1103, 1104
customer_purchase: 300, 256, 29, 418

I tried creating a new table with LEFT JOIN, however there were too many entries for it to successfully compute. Now I'm trying to find a way around altering or creating a new table while still being able to find the sum of purchases by state.

Comment: I don't see anything in the attempt code you've provided that would result in the "sum of purchases by state". Tangentially, as it stands right now, we can't possibly provide a concrete answer without knowing where the total purchase value is stored.

Comment: Make it easy (and possible) to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Skip those parentheses enclosing the select list. Don't you want one column for customer_id and one for customer_purchase, instead of a row-type?

Comment: Some sample data would also be helpful, as would the name of the DBMS you are using. Oh, and the structure of the _customers_ and the _parchases_ tables.

Comment: Those parentheses around the column list are completely useless. Most databases will even reject that query. Is that what you mean with "crashing it"? Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: When I say it crashed, I mean it would compute for about a minute and have gotten to around 2 million entries calculated before freezing and not responding. I would then have to use task manager to quit the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret correctly, you simply want to aggregate total purchases by state.  Presuming a few things (like customer_id is unique in customer_table), I think the following will lead you in the right direction: **untested**

```
SELECT cust.customer_state, sum(purch.customer_purchase) TotalByState
FROM customer_table AS cust
INNER JOIN purchase_table AS purch ON purch.customer_id = cust.customer_id
GROUP BY cust.customer_state
```

Comment: That solved it. Thank you very much. Can I ask why you chose INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN?

Comment: I didn't think about it too much.  I guess a left join would be better if you want to include states with no purchases.  Might need `isnull(sum(purch.customer_purchase),0)` to show no purchases as 0.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements a bit vague.
If you need sum of all customer purchases against state, then use the answer by Avery.

If you want the total of state against each row, you can use the following.

```
SELECT *, SUM(pt.customer_purchase) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_state, ORDER BY GETDATE())
FROM Customer_table ct
INNER JOIN purchase_table pt
ON ct.customer_id = pt.customer_id
```